# apex:repeat - select all check boxes

Tags: visualforce, repeat, inputcheckboxes, selectcheckboxes

I have used `<apex:repeat>` tag to display records in table using paging. In which I have used `<apex:selectCheckboxes>` to select the checkbox for that particular record . What should I do to select all the records of a particular page (select all checkbox)? Can anyone provide an example for it?

[image]

When I select my GSS Reco's it has to select the remaining checkboxes in the current page.

Comment: Do one thing give any class to all `<apex:selectCheckboxes>` and use jquery or JS to get all the checkbox based on ClassName and make it true or false `$(".ClassName").attr("checked", "true");`

Comment: @Ratan I have tried this earlier. But could not get the proper result, Since I am using apex:repeat

Comment: It should work.. Are facing any issue to implement this?

Comment: Error: Unknown property 'VisualforceArrayList.lstSAPData' @Ratan